# How to resolve warning "◦Value Install Location missing " in windows 7 software logo kit?

Tags: wix, wix3

Hi i am doing certification for first time for exe .Report generated warnings .

```
    1. Clean, reversible, installation    

Test case: Write appropriate Add/Remove Program values: PASS WITH WARNINGS 
•
WARNING:  Applications are expected to create these registry entries DisplayName, InstallLocation, Publisher, UninstallString, VersionMajor*, and VersionMinor*. 
 This application did not create the following registry entries: 
◦Value InstallLocation missing or invalid for program My Service.

•
IMPACT IF NOT FIXED: A user might remove an application not only to free up disk space, but also to return the computer to its state prior to the application being installed. Failure to restore the machine to its original state is a poor user experience. Also applications that do not create the above registry entries will not be found by enterprise inventory tools, and may experience issues in OS migrations and or upgrades scenarios. Windows telemetry tools may not accurately report information about your application.  

•
HOW TO FIX: You can supply all of the information needed to configure Add/Remove Programs in Control Panel by setting the values of certain installer properties in your application's Windows Installer package. Setting these properties automatically writes the corresponding values into the registry. The latest information and best practices that illustrate how to do this can be found at these links 1 and 2.  



Test case: Do not force an immediate reboot during installation: PASS 



Test case: Do not force an immediate reboot during uninstallation: PASS 



Test case: Remove all non-shared files and folders: PASS
```

how to resolve this through wix file?

In my wix file i am creating entry's for

Service installation
Create and add entries to ini file
Add registry entries for customer tag and agent id..

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an MSI-based installation you get InstallLocation in the ARP entries by setting the ARPINSTALLLOCATION property to the actual install folder (after it's determined of course).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367589(v=vs.85).aspx

and there's a note at the bottom about setting it with WiX.